# include files from specific folder

Tags: input, include, environment-variables

New linux (mint) user, with pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian), using TexStudio (that might change)

I have custom files (sty's and whatnot) in a folder that I cannot move (shared with other computers) that I would like to be able to `\include` or `\input` in all my tex files (including when I use TexStudio or another editor with building capabilities).

On windows, I'm able to create an environment variable `TEXINPUTS` to include that folder on latex (miktex) search path. On linux mint I tried (failed) the following :

- directly in a terminal with `export TEXINPUTS=~/Dropbox/Templates//:` (only works inside said terminal)
- Adding the previous line in `.bashrc, .profile and /etc/environment`. The first one made it work in any terminal.

Now it works in TexStudio if I launch TexStudio from any terminal. But not if I launch it from GUI. Is there a file I'm missing that could affect GUI launched applications ? Barring that a way to make it like texstudio was launched from a terminal ?

I also looked into :

There is supposed to be a `texmf` folder I can put files in, so I figured I could put a symbolic link to my folder there, but :

- I haven't done a symbolic link in ~ 15 years
- I can't find said `texmf` folder...

(apparently that would be bad)

Any help welcome !

Comment: `export TEXINPUTS=/Dropbox/Templates//: ` will work (in that terminal session) as long as you are using bash or similar shell if (for some reason) you are using csh it would be setenv rather than export. Once you get it working iteractively you can put the appropriate line in your .bash_profile or similar setup file (get back to that later once the commandline setting works)

Comment: is Dropbox really at the root of your filesystem?

Comment: ok, my bad it is not at the root but inside ~. ~/Dropbox/Templates//: works indeed in the terminal session (i'm still a bit confused by ~). But only inside the terminal, not inside texstudio

Comment: `~` is your home directory usually `/home/imj/` or some such.  texstudio (if launched from your desktop) will not be in a shell below the terminal in which you made the interactive setting, you will need to add the line to your .bash_profile (and re-start) or (most likely) texstudio will have a setting within its own configuration (but I don't have texstudio so I'll leave others to answer)

Comment: this is exactly the same as windows, if you just set the variable in a cmd window it would not affect editors started from your desktop

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : I understand that, and the question becomes : Where do I set it, then ?

Comment: as I said in your startup file (so it is set in all your shells) which may be .profile or .bash_profile or .login or some other possibilities depending how your linux is set up, or (I assume) you could set it as part of the texstudio config but I don't have texstudio (or linux:-)

Comment: @KJO : ok I had a long comment detailling my situation, but It appears I didn't understand everything. My dropbox contains the templates folder, which contains tex files that I input/include from nearly every tex document I create. And a lots of others folders with 1k small tex files using those.

I am *not* using any texmf folder, nor on windows (2 computers) nor on linux (yet anyway)

Comment: I edited the question to reflect the progress made. Now it works if TexStudio is launched from a temrinal (where TEXINPUTS is set via .bashrc). Anyway to set it without a terminal ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but you lost me again, I thought what you were talking about had nothing to to with EnvVars (which are defined on the computers separately). And dropbox copies files locally, doesn't it ?  :( anyway I have been using that setup (windows only though) for almost 10 years without incidents (aside from the occasional small conflict), I'm just trying to make it work on this unix computer.

Comment: @KJO : still lost. Your last sentence is way too long. I still don't get how my setup could be harmful in any way. I'm just compiling "file.tex" in my dropbox folder. The first line of file.tex is '\input{Stuff}', where Stuff is a file inside the Templates folder. Therefore I need latex to search for "Stuff" inside that folder.

Comment: @KJO : Ok. Therefore :a) id like not to use texmf as apparently it requires texhash to map the contents after changes ? b)  my templates folder only contains tex files I made myself (bunch of usepackages and newcommands) c) i m the only user, so dropbox sync period not a issue.  I'm good ?

Comment: @KDO Yep. I make a full backup from time to time, and as not all three computers are connected at the same time I can boot without network to get the local version in case it gets corrupted/missing from the cloud.